# -to value smaller than -ss error while clipping videos with ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am trying to clip videos using frame information, I first convert the frame to time since ffmpeg uses this notion to clip videos.

The problem is for shorter videos, it gives the error:

`-to;` value smaller than `-ss;` aborting.

But in reality, this is false. For example, I get an error even with these values:

```
0:0:47.4 -to 0:0:47.21  (format -> hh:mm:ss.frame)
```

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this?

The video frame rate is 25 fps and the command structure I use is:

```
 os.system('ffmpeg -i ' + inputvideo + '.mp4' + ' -qscale:v 2 -vf scale=427:240 ' + ' -ss '+ str(fhours) + ':' + str(fminutes) + ':' + str(fseconds) + '.' + str(fframes) + ' -to ' + str(lhours) + ':' + str(lminutes) + ':' + str(lseconds) + '.' + str(lframes) + ' ' + outputvideo + '.avi')
```

Comment: `0:0:47.4 -to 0:0:47.21` --> The latter is indeed smaller.  `.4` != `.04`

Comment: It is not a decimal though, with ffmpeg the last part is the number of the frame (hh:mm:ss.keyframe) so 21>4 no?

Comment: No, last part is milliseconds - see https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Time-duration

Comment: Ohh, okay, thanks. I also found more explanation (for others having the same misconception): Note that you can use two different time unit formats: sexagesimal (HOURS:MM:SS.MILLISECONDS, as in 01:23:45.678), or in seconds. If a fraction is used, such as 02:30.05, this is interpreted as "5 100ths of a second", not as frame 5. For instance, 02:30.5 would be 2 minutes, 30 seconds, and a half a second, which would be the same as using 150.5 in seconds.

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking#Timeunitsyntax